# problems with jruby version of ruby-debug

Tags: ruby, jruby, ruby-debug

**This problem no longer exists. ruby-debug works fine in jruby these days**

Whenever I use 'n' to step over a line it steps into it instead. This happens to me on all the versions of jruby i've tried, the latest being 1.3.1

Does it work right for anyone? If so any idea how to fix it, because it's too painful when it steps into every function every time.

Also, I use it like this if it makes any difference.

```
require 'ruby-debug'; debugger
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too. Have you tried using "step" instead, "step" seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

currently doesn't work with 1.4.0 either, but ruby-debug does work with a trunk build of jruby